# the execution order of java annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have some Java annotations of a method, how can I know the order of each annotation aspect? And how I can specify the order of them.

```
@MyAnnotaion
@Cacheable
@HystrixCommand
public void MYMethod() {}
```

`Cacheable` is from SpringCache and `HystrixCommand` is from third party package, and they are both runtime annotations, I need `Cacheable` to run before `HystrixCommand`, but cannot mark them with `@order`.

So, how can I :

1、learn the order of annotation execution?

2、specify the order?

I have tried to search the problem, but if duplicated , please let me know.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering this talks about the order of aspect, but still I cannot change the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[you can mark order in enable caching](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html) , but this will be application wide setting

```
@EnableCaching(order=0)
```

> Indicate the ordering of the execution of the caching advisor when
>   multiple advices are applied at a specific joinpoint.